# How to block direct access to templates (hiding templates)

Tags: templating, hiding

How can I prevent people accessing templates directly that are only used as includes for instance?

I read that I could add an underscore ie _example.html,but then the include stops working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your template is *_example.html*, you include like this:

```
{% include '_example.html' %}
```

It also works to have a template in a directory that starts with an underscore. So you could name the directory *_includes*, name the template in there *example.html* and include it like this:

```
{% include '_includes/example.html' %}
```

Either way, the template can't be accessed directly.

Comment: Ah, I missed the point (facepalm) Since you also need to adjust the include I thought you could still access the template with the underscore added. But then it's blocked